# For keycloak-19.0.3-legacy docker image, how can I enable redirect_uri legacy functionality?

Tags: docker, keycloak

I need to set the flags to enable the default redirect_uri behavior for keycloak 19.0.3-legacy.
However, nothing I've tried so far has worked.
We're using the standalone-ha.xml configuration file. (not sure if this is the could be the right place to configure this.)

I need to set the following flags:

```
spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-suppress-logout-confirmation-screen=true
spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true
```

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/19.0.3/upgrading/#openid-connect-logout-prompt
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/#openid-connect-logout

However, I run a standalone instance and don't run using `kc.sh`.

I've tried setting environment variables without success:

```
KC_SPI_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_OPENID_CONNECT_LEGACY_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI=true
KC_SPI_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_OPENID_CONNECT_SUPPRESS_LOGOUT_CONFIRMATION_SCREEN=true

and

KEYCLOAK_SPI_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_OPENID_CONNECT_LEGACY_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI=true
KEYCLOAK_SPI_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_OPENID_CONNECT_SUPPRESS_LOGOUT_CONFIRMATION_SCREEN=true

and

SPI_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_OPENID_CONNECT_LEGACY_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI=true
SPI_LOGIN_PROTOCOL_OPENID_CONNECT_SUPPRESS_LOGOUT_CONFIRMATION_SCREEN=true

and

LEGACY_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI=true
SUPPRESS_LOGOUT_CONFIRMATION_SCREEN=true
```

I've also tried to adding to a config file, but it doesn't seem to have been picked up from where it was put in the Dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
COPY conf.d/keycloak.conf /opt/jboss/keycloak/conf/keycloak.conf

and

COPY conf.d/keycloak.conf /opt/keycloak/conf/keycloak.conf
```

keycloak.conf

```
spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-suppress-logout-confirmation-screen=true
spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true

and

suppress-logout-confirmation-screen=true
legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true
```

I also tried adding it to thedocker-entrypoint.sh parameters:

```
exec /opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh $@ -Dspi-login-protocol-openid-connect-suppress-logout-confirmation-screen=true -Dspi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true

and

--This one won't even start up. It fails stating that the parameters are invalid.
exec /opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh $@ --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-suppress-logout-confirmation-screen=true --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true
```

##### Update 1/24/23

Tried updating standalone-ha.xml, but it seems to have been ignored:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1">
            <web-context>auth</web-context>
            <providers>
                <provider>
                    classpath:${jboss.home.dir}/providers/*
                </provider>
                <provider>
                    module:org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPSyncOnly
                </provider>
            </providers>
            <master-realm-name>master</master-realm-name>
            <scheduled-task-interval>900</scheduled-task-interval>
            <theme>
                <staticMaxAge>2592000</staticMaxAge>
                <cacheThemes>false</cacheThemes>
                <cacheTemplates>false</cacheTemplates>
                <welcomeTheme>${env.KEYCLOAK_WELCOME_THEME:keycloak}</welcomeTheme>
                <default>${env.KEYCLOAK_DEFAULT_THEME:keycloak}</default>
                <dir>${jboss.home.dir}/themes</dir>
            </theme>
            ... Bunch of other spi tags. ...
            <spi name="login-protocol">
                <provider name="openid-connect" enabled="true">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="suppress-logout-confirmation-screen" value="true"/>
                        <property name="legacy-logout-redirect-uri" value="true"/>
                    </properties>
                </provider>
            </spi>
        </subsystem>
```

Useful links:

- https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/10b7475b0431ed380d45b840578bc666ecb3263a/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/OIDCLoginProtocolFactory.java#L106-L121

  - Shows the warning message that will print to the logs if this is set correctly.
- https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration#_example_configuring_the_db_url_host_parameter

  - Shows alternate ways to configure keycloak.
- https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/tree/19.0.3
- https://quay.io/repository/keycloak/keycloak?tab=tags

Comment: Did you try using JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-suppress-logout-confirmation-screen=true " ?

Comment: I think so, but I'll try it againe with `--` `no dash` and `-D` to be sure.

Comment: I did try multiple versions of `SERVER_OPTS` `KEYCLOAK_SERVER_OPTS` `KC_SERVER_OPTS` `EXTRA_ARGS_PREPENDED` `KEYCLOAK_EXTRA_ARGS_PREPENDED`  `KC_EXTRA_ARGS_PREPENDED` without luck.

Comment: @dreamcrash
- Doesn't start up w/ `--****` or `-D***`:
  - `Unrecognized option: --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true`
  - `Error: Could not find or load main class spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true`
||| Ignored -D**** options

Comment: Correction to previous comment: `--***` and `no prefix` cause the pod to fail to start up. `-D***` is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured it out.
By adding the following CLI commands we can properly update the high availability config file to enable the legacy flag.

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=login-protocol:add
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=login-protocol/provider=openid-connect:add(enabled=true)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=login-protocol/provider=openid-connect:write-attribute(name=properties.legacy-logout-redirect-uri,value=true)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=login-protocol/provider=openid-connect:write-attribute(name=properties.suppress-logout-confirmation-screen,value=true)
stop-embedded-server
```

I don't know why this worked but manually editing the standalone-ha.xml config didn't.